# Query result of latest timestamp if required value not available

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a psql database in which per minute result of around thousands of key values are being updated. For reporting purpose, I need hourly results exactly at full hours i.e. 9:00, 10:00) etc. My data is like this:

```
timestamp       tag value
2019-06-06 06:00:00 x   123
2019-06-06 06:00:00 y   456
2019-06-06 06:01:00 x   123
2019-06-06 06:01:00 y   656
2019-06-06 06:02:00 x   123 
2019-06-06 06:02:00 y   333 
.......
.......
2019-06-06 06:59:00 x   2232
2019-06-06 06:59:00 y   654
2019-06-06 07:00:00 x   5645
2019-06-06 07:00:00 y   54654
```

And to get result like below:,

```
timestamp               tag value
2019-06-06 06:00:00     x   123
2019-06-06 06:00:00     y   456
2019-06-06 07:00:00     x   5645
2019-06-06 07:00:00     y   54654
...
.....
......
2019-06-09 07:00:00     x   5645
2019-06-09 07:00:00     y   54654
```

I have used below code:

```sql
select *
from test
where date_trunc('hour', "timestamp") = "timestamp";
```

But according to above query results exactly at full hour will be given. But sometimes, some of these keys are not being updated exactly at full hour like this:

```
timestamp       tag value
2019-06-06 05:59:00 x   123
2019-06-06 05:59:00 y   456
2019-06-06 06:01:00 x   123
2019-06-06 06:01:00 y   656
```

In above case , I will be given null result for 6:00:00.

I want query that will automatically pass last value i.e. value at 05:59:00 in above case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the range of time your interested in not just the 'beginning'. So

```
    with test as 
   ( select * from
          ( values ('2019-06-06 05:59:00'::timestamp without time zone, 'x', 123)    
                 , ('2019-06-06 05:59:00'::timestamp without time zone, 'y', 456)
                 , ('2019-06-06 06:01:00'::timestamp without time zone, 'x', 123)           
                 , ('2019-06-06 06:01:00'::timestamp without time zone, 'y', 656)          
          )
        as t (act_ts ,tag, value  
        )        
    )   
select act_ts,tag,value
     , lower(tsrange(date_trunc('hour',act_ts),date_trunc('hour',act_ts+interval '1 hour'), '[)')) as from_time 
     , upper(tsrange(date_trunc('hour',act_ts),date_trunc('hour',act_ts+interval '1 hour'), '[)')) as time     
  from test
 where act_ts <@ tsrange(date_trunc('hour',act_ts),date_trunc('hour',act_ts+interval '1 hour'), '[)') 
 order by tag,lower(tsrange(date_trunc('hour',act_ts),date_trunc('hour',act_ts+interval '1 hour'), '[)') );
```

The above generates a time range of each hour via the tsrange function:

```
tsrange(date_trunc('hour',act_ts),date_trunc('hour',act_ts+interval '1 hour'), '[)'))
```

The above generates a timestamp between the hour of act_ts (I hope your column name is not actually "timestamp"). Notice the final parameter '[)'. This tells Postgres to include the lower range value but exclude the upper range value. Reference Postgres [Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/rangetypes.html).
I've added a additional columns and an order by for demonstration purposed that would not be necessary in a implementation query. That could be just:

```
select act_ts,tag,value
  from test
 where act_ts <@ tsrange(date_trunc('hour',act_ts),date_trunc('hour',act_ts+interval '1 hour'), '[)');
```